# Cannot resolve error in vanilla IIS-hosted WCF example: The type [...] provided as the Service attribute value [...] could not be found

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

The text of this error is reported often here on Stack Overflow, but none of the resolutions apply to our situation.  **The code in question could not be more simple.  It comes from the Microsoft IIS-hosted WCF service example (a simple Calculator service) at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx]**[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The gist of the error is the oft-reported "The type [...] provided as the Service attribute value [...] could not be found."  I've attached a screen snapshot of the full error text.  Also here are my code samples for the service and config files, the interface, and the code.

For what it's worth, I get the same "type provided could not be found" error for any WCF service I try to host in IIS using the methods described by Microsoft.  These are all simple "hello world" programs.  We've tried moving the code to other machines in the building and hosting there but we get the same error.  We've tried on Windows 2003 Server and Windows 8.  We're developing in VS 2013 with the .Net 4.5 Framework.

Any and all help appreciated...

Service.svc:

```
<%@ServiceHost language=c# Debug="true" Service="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"%>
```

ICalculatorService.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Divide(double n1, double n2);
    }
}
```

CalculatorService.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
{
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            return n1 + n2;
        }
        public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
        {
            return n1 - n2;
        }
        public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
        {
            return n1 * n2;
        }
        public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
        {
            return n1 / n2;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the default configuration model introduced in .NET Framework 4 -->
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService">

        <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host:  http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />

        <!-- The mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

The error:
[image]

And, finally, I added an IIS application via inetmgr that points to the location of my app:
[image]

Which is found here:

[image]

Comment: I would start by changing the Service attribute in your svc file to include the fully-qualified name of the assembly containing the service, and check that this assembly is present in the bin folder.  The sample you linked puts the service implementation in the App_Code folder, whereas you appear to be putting it into an Assembly - in which case you need to tell IIS which Assembly to use.

Comment: Do you see assembly generated in bin folder after project build?

Comment: I appreciate the replies.  Yes the assembly is in the bin folder.  I am unclear as to what the suggested mod should be: there's very little documentation on what a svc file should look like.  I DID try dropping the .svc and .config files into the same folder as CalculatorService.dll and repointing the IIS app straight to that folder, but I get the same results.

Comment: Try deleting Temporary File from C:\Windows\Microsof.Net\Framework\version\Temporary asp.net files.

Comment: We did try that one Pankaj, good suggestion.  No joy, but we did solve it.  Apparently there is a default location relative to the .svc file where the assembly should be located.  I posted screen snapshots as an answer below.  Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try decorating the `CalculatorService` class with the `[ServiceBehavior]`-attribute.

```
namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
{
    [ServiceBehavior]
    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        //...
```

Comment: Why serviceBehavior required here?

Comment: Thank you for the reply khlr.  This has no effect.  I am wondering what the intended effect was?

Answer (score 0):

Argh!  So apparently there is a default location relative to the service file where, when the assembly is placed, all works as it should.  **Placing the assembly in a \bin subfolder of the folder holding the .svc file yields a working service.**

As you would expect, the compiler is generating CalculatorService.dll in either [projectfolder]\bin\debug or [projectfolder]\bin\release.  With the .svc file in [projectfolder], you get the error.

Simply moving the dll up one level to the \bin folder cures the problem.  This seems a little counter-intuitive... I would have thought if it was a default folder problem it'd make more sense to have the .svc file in the same location as the .dll.  The Microsoft example really gives no clues.  Anyway, for future reference, here is what works with the code samples taken from Microsoft's web site:

Location of the .svc file:
[image]

Location of the assembly:
[image]

And IIS is configured to point to the location of the .svc file, as stated in the the original problem description:
[image]

Browsing to the URL as per the Microsoft article we now see what we'd hoped for:
[image]

Comment: Host sites don't get "built" with configurations like Debug and Release, they just get published. Also, you might find it useful to skip the .svc file altogether, and just use a `serviceActivation`: <serviceActivations>
<add relativeAddress="service.svc" service="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"/>
</serviceActivations>

Comment: "the compiler is generating CalculatorService.dll in either [projectfolder]\bin\debug" - this is normal for a class library project,but you should probably be using an ASP.NET web application project, in which case it will generate the assemblies in the bin folder.

Comment: Thank you for the replies and the very useful information.  This all makes perfect sense now that we've worked through the problem.